# Why title_li ='' not working

Tags: categories

I want to hide the 'Categories' and used the following code

```
<?php
                    $args = array(
                        'parent'            => 33, 
                        'show_count'        => 1,
                        'title_li='         => __( '' ),
                        'hide_empty'        => 0,
                    );
                    wp_list_categories($args)
                    ?>
```

But it is not working, why? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the parameter name is `title_li` and not `title_li=`. It also doesn't make sense of using `__( '' )`, so I'd change that to just `''`.

```php
// When the args is a query string, title_li= works.
$args = 'title_li=';

// But when the args is an array, use just title_li.
$args = array(
    'title_li=' => '', // bad
    'title_li'  => '', // good
);
```

Comment: oh, you are right. The typo is hard to find. Thank you so much!